# using get and set methods to pass an array between two classes (java)

Tags: java

In my class ReadInput, i read a file containing integers separated by space one by one and put them into inputArray. I then want to use inputArray (and its size) in my class B and i'm attempting to do that with get and set methods but I guess i'm not using them correctly and can't pinpoint my error. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadInput 
{
        String INPUT_FILE_NAME = "pages.dat"; // filename
        private int [] inputArray;
        private int size;



public ReadInput()
  {
      Scanner fileIn=null;  //(Initialization keeps compiler happy)
      try { // open file
          fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE_NAME));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("Input file "+INPUT_FILE_NAME+" not found. ");
          System.exit(1);
      } 

      while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            String word = fileIn.next();
            size++;

        }

      inputArray = new int [size];
      //test to see that it gives correct size
      System.out.println(size);

      fileIn.close(); // close file

      try { // open file
          fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE_NAME));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("Input file "+INPUT_FILE_NAME+" not found. ");
          System.exit(1);
      } 


      int i=0;
      while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            inputArray[i] = fileIn.nextInt();
            i++;
        }

      fileIn.close();
  }

      public  int [] getinputArray()
      {
          return inputArray;
      }

      public  void setinputArray(int [] inputArray)
      {
          this.inputArray = inputArray;
      }

      public  int getSize()

      {
          return size;
      }

      public void setsize(int size)
      {
          this.size = size;
      }
}

public class B 
{

    ReadInput in = new ReadInput();

    int [] inputs;

    public B()
    {

    }


    //this method does not work and gives an error
   public void method()
    {
       System.out.println("in FIFO: " + in.getSize());


      for(int j=0; j< inputs.length; j++)
         System.out.print(inputs[j] + " ");

    }

}
```

Comment: Your code would not compile right now. For example, in `B`'s constructor, you say `inputs = new int[in.getSize()];` but `in` is not defined.

Comment: @Jashaszun yes it is i have the code write below where i declare class B, ReadInput in = new ReadInput();

Comment: Ah never mind... I completely missed that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `B`'s constructor, you need to call `in.initializeArrays()` and `in.getJobs()`.

Right now, `in.getSize()` is `0` since that's the default value of `ReadInput.size`. In addition, `in.getInputArray()` will be `null` since that is the default value of `ReadInput.inputArray`.

Alternatively, you could remove `ReadInput.initializeArrays()` and `ReadInput.getJobs()` and simply move the code into a zero-argument constructor for `ReadInput`, like so:

```
class ReadInput {
    // previous fields: size, inputArray, etc.
    public ReadInput() {
        // code for setting size and populating inputArray from the file
    }
    // other methods: getJobs, etc.
}
```

If you do this, then you should be set. You're already calling `ReadInput`'s constructor through your `ReadInput in = new ReadInput();` line, so that line should then populate `in`'s data.

Comment: I took ur suggestion of moving the code to a zero input constructor but now when i try to print the array from class B i get all 0s as output

Comment: @Chalupa That's because you never populate `inputArray` in `initializeArrays()`. I see `inputArray = new int [size];` but you don't do anything else with it. You probably need to call `in.getJobs()` as well to actually populate `inputArray`.

Comment: i populate it in ReadInput.getJobs()

Comment: @Chalupa Yes, exactly, that's why I said you need to call that method.

Comment: in order to make things simpler i moved the codes for both initializeArrays() and getJobs into the zero argument constructor. what would i have to add to B's constructor to be able to use the array now?

Comment: @Chalupa Same with my answer. It should now work. If it doesn't, then give me a specific error message and line.

Comment: i'm getting null pointer exception on line: for(int j=0; j< inputs.length; j++)  in class B

Comment: i managed to fix it by adding in.getinputArray(); in B.method(). thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In B's constructor, I don't see you calling

> in.initializeArrays

or

> setinputArray(int [] inputArray)

anywhere to actually set the array before getting the size.